# Shell via PHP: Trouble adding new cron job to crontab

Tags: php, linux, shell, nginx, cron

I have several scripts scheduled to run in my crontab, but can only see them as root (or using sudo).  I need to have a PHP script (which is being run as nginx) be able to add a new line to the crontab file.  To do this I created a shell script (owned by root) and gave the `nginx` user permission to `sudo` it via the `/etc/sudoers` file.

The last line of the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
nginx ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/nginx/addcron.sh
```

The PHP call to execute the script:

```
chdir("/etc/nginx/");
echo exec("2>&1 ./addcron.sh $custname", $output);
echo "<pre>".print_r($output, true)."</pre>";
```

My current crontab:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-xx-xxx nginx]$ sudo crontab -l
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/example/cron/cron.php
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/demo/cron/cron.php
0 23 * * * rm /tmp/cachegrind.out.*
```

Meta information about my `addcron.sh` file:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-xx-xxx nginx]$ pwd
/etc/nginx
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-xx-xxx nginx]$ ls -al addcron.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 129 Nov 24 22:16 addcron.sh
```

The contents of `addcron.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
custname="$1"
(crontab -l; echo \"* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/$custname/cron/cron.php\" ) | crontab -
```

When I try to run this though, I get the following error:

```
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Array
(
    [0] => "-":102: bad minute
    [1] => errors in crontab file, can't install.
)
```

It seems like it doesn't like the `-` mark in `addcron.sh`, but my Google searches suggest this is correct.  Also, I have tried adding `sudo` to the PHP's `exec` command, but then I just get the following error:

```
sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

What am I doing wrong or missing, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side note: running cron jobs unrelated to the system admin under the `root`'s account is a **BAD IDEA** from the security prospective. Install your crons under the `nginx` user.

The issue is caused by the escaping of the quotes in your bash script (which you can check directly in bash, piece by piece, btw):

```
> (crontab -l; echo \"* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/$custname/cron/cron.php\" )
no crontab for username
"* ... <all kinds of filenames in here> ... /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/the_customer/cron/cron.php"
```

Without the quote escaping things work a bit better:

```
> (crontab -l; echo "* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/$custname/cron/cron.php" )
no crontab for username
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/the_customer/cron/cron.php
```

You might want to add some protection against duplicating the entries, here's how crontab looks after a few invocations:

```
> crontab -l
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (- installed on Tue Nov 24 20:54:10 2015)
# (Cronie version 4.2)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (- installed on Tue Nov 24 20:54:09 2015)
# (Cronie version 4.2)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (- installed on Tue Nov 24 20:54:09 2015)
# (Cronie version 4.2)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (- installed on Tue Nov 24 20:54:08 2015)
# (Cronie version 4.2)
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (- installed on Tue Nov 24 20:54:07 2015)
# (Cronie version 4.2)
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/the_customer/cron/cron.php
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/the_customer/cron/cron.php
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/the_customer/cron/cron.php
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/the_customer/cron/cron.php
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/the_customer/cron/cron.php
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into tightening the security.  removing the quotes got rid of the error message, but the `crontab -e` still has the same content, which is odd; I'd expect either an error or the content to be added, but neither happened.

Comment: Are you checking the crontab for the right user (the one invoking the script or `root` if executed under sudo)?

Comment: The one invoking the script is `nginx` and when I try to `su` to them, or run commands as them (`runuser -l nginx -c 'crontab -l'`) I get the message `This account is currently not available.`  I'm trying to run it under `root` which is why I added the bit of `nginx ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/nginx/addcron.sh` to `/etc/sudoers`, but `sudo crontab -l` doesn't show the new entries, which is why I'm confused, since there's no error message either.

Comment: Turns out the reason I didn't get any error message after was because it WAS being added -- just to the `nginx` user, not to `root`.  I never figured out how to change it, but I also realized I don't need or want to, so I'm good.  Thank you Dan!

Answer (score 0):

I recently published a project that allows PHP to obtain and interact with a real Bash shell. Get it here: https://github.com/merlinthemagic/MTS

After downloading you would simply use the following code:

```
$custname= "someone";
$strCmd = "echo \"* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/".$custname."\" >> /cron/cron.php";

$shell    = \MTS\Factories::getDevices()->getLocalHost()->getShell('bash', true);
$return1  = $shell->exeCmd($strCmd);
//assuming your distribution reloads / restarts using 'service'
$return2  = $shell->exeCmd('service crond restart');
```

this will append your line to the cron file.